Canon 600D Kiss X5 Optical Viewfinder Vignette Using Canon EF 50mm 1.8
Canon 600D Kiss X5 Optical Viewfinder Vignette Using Canon EF 50mm 1.8
Hi, is it normal to get a heavy vignette (large round border) using a 50mm 1.8 through the viewfinder (photos are ok as is the LCD screen view) I have tried 2 50mm one being STM. Not able to try another lens (but have one coming 70 -300)
Is this how it is?
Thanks in advance.

Has it been repaired lately? Is there a chance it got reassembled with a fresnel on the focusing screen missing?

Thanks for your reply, don't know as just purchased off ebay it's in great condition,  the border is on seen in the viewfinder :-(

The 'viewfinder' on any SLR is built from a a focusing screen the light from the lens is bounced-onto with a mirror and a pentaprism that lets you look at the focusing screen right side up. There's visible light falloff as the angle of light becomes wider so usually a Fresnel lens is placed just in front of the focusing screen to correct the angle before it hits.  If that's missing it might look like this.

Do you wear any type of glasses?

davolfman thanks I will check  Rafael yes wear glasses but still an issue with otr without, thanks for ur reply

Guys I think I bought a dodgy repair job as there is no focus screen I can see above the mirror, I can see directly into viewfinfder area from front of screen and no focus dots when looking through finder LOL

@Admin the focus screen is removable/replaceable... and they are not very costly.

@davolfman, good call on the missing focus screen; but the screen is also the/a fresnel... they are not separate components.

Steven Kersting yes I watched video on the focus screen, cheers, I will send it back as there also 2 dots on images, maybe sensor picxel or dirt, but it should not have missing parts when sold. Thanks LOL.... oh dear!

Make sure your other lens coming is an EF 70-300mm. The much cheaper 75-300 series are the worst lenses Canon has ever sold for DSLRs. (Exception: The 1995 EF 75-300mm f/4-5.6 IS USM is a decent budget telephoto, as it's a totally different lens that was the design predecessor to the 70-300mm f/4-5.6 series, though the APS-C only EF-S 55-250mm is about as good optically on an APS-C body, and usually cheaper.) But the non-IS 75-300mm series - 1991 EF 75-300mm f/4-5.6, 1992 EF 75-300mm f/4-5.6 USM, 1995 EF 75-300mm f/4-5.6 II / II USM, 1999 EF 75-300mm f/4-5.6 III / III USM - are not very good.

The EF lenses are suitable for full frame sensors, which means they project an image circle much larger than what is used by your APS camera; there should be no notable optical vignetting.
The only thing I can think of would be a lens attachment that is far too deep (E.g. a stack of filters). Otherwise there must be something wrong with the camera.

Thank you for your reply Steven, strange all canon lenses 2 50mm so don't think they are faulty, no other attachments, if I take the lens off, there is no vignetting

To clarify for those coming later:
This turned out to be a symptom of a dSLR with no focusing screen. That turned the pentaprism and lens into an optical viewfinder but that didn't work with the 50mm. This condition also prevents normal autofocus and metering with the mirror down.
